# 74HC574 or 74LS377?

Tags: flipflop

Can any one tell me if the 74HC574 replaces the 74LS377 in a circuit of a frequency counter ? I looked at their data sheet and found out they are similar regardless their pin out, may be i'm missing some the big picture ao that's why i'm asking precisely if they do function the same, thanks for any info that helps.

Comment: Logic family difference: `HC` versus `LS`. Look at thresholds and speeds.

Comment: In logic terms, yes. Physically, maybe. Loaded LS outputs are not guaranteed to be able to drive HC inputs. Even unloaded outputs aren't consistent, unless you use a pullup resistor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does 74HC574 replaces the 74LS377?

If this implies can it be blindly substituted for an existing design using 74LS part?

> NO

This mainly due to Vih(min) threshold can exceed Voh guaranteed if driven by another 74LSxx part and differences in the Disable function. (EN_low)

> THe reason the part numbers changed root number xxx is due to the functional differences in output enable to tri-state for the HC version.

If one needed 74LSxx input compatibility then the 74HCT574 is a better choice.

But **yes** they more or less perform the same tasked as a gated 8 bit D latch, 
except the difference in functions are ...

The LS version is enables changes on input data to be clocked while the output is always active

The HC version is output tri-state enabled , while the data input clock latch is always active. ( somewhat opposite)